# Regex Matching Datetime - optional second half?

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression to match a variety of different MM/dd/yy format timestamps, including time. I created this one and it worked fine for a while:

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?\d\d()( (?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)( AM| PM)?)?
```

https://regex101.com/r/iV1kF8/2

Until I realized that the timestamps I'm matching could also have a " - " separating the date and time. I altered the expression to this:

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?\d\d(?: ?| - ?)(?:(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)( AM| PM)?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/iV1kF8/3

It matches the format with the hyphen, but breaks matches with timestamps that don't include time. I was under the impression that adding `(?: ?| - ?)` would match zero or one space OR zero or one of " - " -- looking at this now, I realize it's more like matching " -" plus zero or one of " ".

Either way, I'm not quite sure why, at the very least, the `(?: ?` portion isn't taking care of the timestamps without the following time.

I've also tried enclosing the entire second half in parentheses and adding a `?` modifier to it to try to make the whole second half optional, which seems to fix the timestamps without time, but also breaks the matches for the stamps with the hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this regex:

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?\d\d((?: |\s*-\s*)(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)( AM| PM)?)?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fC7gY9/1)

I just added `(?: |\s*-\s*)` and removed empty round brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
(0?[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)?\d\d ?-?( ?(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)( AM| PM)?)?
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iV1kF8/4)